# Reformat code and CSS completion in Intellij IDEA

Tags: html, css, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

A very long time in Intellij IDEA reformat code for CSS and code completion doesn't work. When I type ctrl+alt+l nothing changes whatever is in the file. I think that's not expected behavior. How to change it? CSS plugin is enabled.

Comment: Does the file appear with CSS icon and [correctly mapped to the file type](https://i.imgur.com/o40SH1B.png)?

Comment: You are right. Pattern *.css was assign to Text. I reassigned it to stylesheet and all works fine. You are the magician. Please make an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common case for the issue is that the file pattern is assigned to Text file type. It can be fixed in File | Settings | Editor | File Types:

[image: CSS]